# What is Default animation duration and curve of PageView swipe Animation?

Tags: flutter, dart

When the pages on page View are swiped it have have a sort of default animation that brings the page to the center of the screen. 
I want the animation curve and duration of this swipe cool down and 
animateTo() on button pressed to be the same.

I have tried all different curves and duration none of that matches the default.
I have also tried using Custom Scroll Physics.

Comment: it does not use animations, it uses physics instead

Comment: @pskink It is possible to match the scroll physics with animation of animateToPage()

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? to follow the `PageView` as it scrolls? if so, use `NotificationListener`

Comment: I want the swipe animation and animation using button to be exactly similar. Similar ease effect

Comment: `"animation using button"` meaning what? you want to animate to other page by clicking a button? if so, use `animateToPage` - you cannot make the same effect as pageview swipe uses physics

Comment: The Page view has both swipe and button to change page. I am unable to replicate the ease effects that swipe has using animateTo

Comment: ok if you swipe your pageview the scrolling can be faster or slower depending on how fast you swiped your page with your finger - so the duration will be longer or shorter, right? so what duration are we talking about?

Comment: I have set the duration of animateTo  to 400ms

Answer (score 7):

In page_view.dart there's an example:

```
_pageController.animateToPage(
  0,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
);
```

I think it's reasonable to assume it uses 400 ms and `easeInOut` as default.